# What piece am I missing to set an iOS background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, background-image

I have:

[A series of if statements sets backgroundImage to be something like [UIImageNamed @"Background-Default-Landscape"]; am I right to assume that the device will look for the file named Background-Default-Landscape@2x.png if it is a Retina display?]

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
CGRect containerRect = CGRectZero;
containerRect.size = [backgroundImage size];
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
[containerView addSubview:backgroundView];
```

Right now my app is launching and once it loads displays a white screen, not a background specified (none of the backgrounds are solid white).

What am I missing to draw a background before I start putting things *on* the background, further below in the code?

Thanks,

--EDIT--

As far as code, I have:

```
- (void) renderScreen
{
    int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    int width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    UIImage *backgroundImage = nil;

    if (height == 2048 || height == 2008 || height == 1024 || height == 1004 || height == 984)
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Portrait"];
    }

    // Other such statements cut. 
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    CGRect containerRect = CGRectZero;
    containerRect.size = [backgroundImage size];
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];

    [containerView addSubview:backgroundView];
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

Then below that are statements to draw on the background.

This method is called when the initial view loads and when it is rotated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self renderScreen];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(renderScreen) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

The behavior is that the correct initial screen loads, then it fades to white and nothing interesting seems to happen after that.

--EDIT--

At the top, I have:

```
int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
int width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
```

When I NSLog the height and width, for a retina device in landscape mode, I get a height of 1024 and a width of 768. The image displayed is a rotation of the portrait image; if I turn the device on the side the image neatly fills the whole screen but as-is the background displays a horizontally squeezed image.

Should I do anything different to be correctly obtaining height and width? I would expect for a device in landscape orientation the height would be 768 and the width would be 1024.

Comment: That all seems correct. We need to see more code. In which method are you adding the view? And to which view are you adding `containerView`?

Comment: Could you put more code? I supose that you're adding containerView to self.view. Also the non-retina image is Default-Background-Labdscape.png (with .png extension).

Comment: @GuyKogus, thank you; I've added more context in the code.

Comment: @JonathanHayward add extension of image in code and try. in this code         backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Portrait"];

Comment: Why are you using the device orientation notifications? If you're using a `UIViewController` class then use the given interface orientation change methods. Also, use `CGFloat` not `int` for width and height. Be consistent with your data types! :)

Comment: Thank you all. @GuyKogus, could you give a link to the right place to be calling this function? (It is intended later on to give full rendering of a screenful of information; right now I'm just working on the background.)

Comment: Now, yes it is, via UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation).

Comment: `UIViewController` has an instance method `interfaceOrientation` that you could be using instead. The status bar's orientation is fine to use too, but it requires calling the `UIApplication` singleton unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time renderScreen fires it will add two more subviews to the current controller's main view:

```
[containerView addSubview:backgroundView];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

And this fires every time you rotate the device.

At least have the containerView as a property and replace it.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;
```

and inside **- (void) renderScreen**

```
[self.containerView  removeFromSuperview];
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
[self.view addSubview:self.containerView];
```

You could also add:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

So that the view is redrawn.

Comment: Thank you; I'm seeing different behavior. It starts black, then changes to white. (This is true with or without [self.containerView setNeedsDisplay]; or [self.view setNeedsDisplay];)

Comment: Where do you set the Landscape image?
If the screen height isn't one of these: (height == 2048 || height == 2008 || height == 1024 || height == 1004 || height == 984) then backgroundImage is still nil

Comment: The code is an accommodation to a gotcha I ran into. In portrait mode, height is 2048 and width is 1536... and in landscape mode, height is still 2048 and width is still 1536. "if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))" is a test to determine whether height is really height, or height is really width.